# Bitmap Support In C++

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

Below is a snippet I've taken from an MSDN example that basically chops a video stream in to small thumbnails at selected intervals:

```
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------
// CreateBitmaps
//
// Creates an array of thumbnails from the video file.
//
// pRT:      Direct2D render target. Used to create the bitmaps.
// count:    Number of thumbnails to create.
// pSprites: An array of Sprite objects to hold the bitmaps.
//
// Note: The caller allocates the sprite objects.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

HRESULT ThumbnailGenerator::CreateBitmaps(
ID2D1RenderTarget *pRT, 
DWORD count, 
Sprite pSprites[]
)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
BOOL bCanSeek = 0;

LONGLONG hnsDuration = 0;
LONGLONG hnsRangeStart = 0;
LONGLONG hnsRangeEnd = 0;
LONGLONG hnsIncrement = 0;

hr = CanSeek(&bCanSeek);

if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

if (bCanSeek)
{
    hr = GetDuration(&hnsDuration);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hnsRangeStart = 0;
    hnsRangeEnd = hnsDuration;

    // We have the file duration , so we'll take bitmaps from
    // several positions in the file. Occasionally, the first frame 
    // in a video is black, so we don't start at time 0.

    hnsIncrement = (hnsRangeEnd - hnsRangeStart) / (count + 1);

}

// Generate the bitmaps and invalidate the button controls so
// they will be redrawn.
for (DWORD i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    LONGLONG hPos = hnsIncrement * (i + 1);

    hr = CreateBitmap(
        pRT, 
        hPos, 
        &pSprites[i]
    );
}

return hr;
}


//
/// Private methods
//

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
 // CreateBitmap
 //
// Creates one video thumbnail.
//
// pRT:      Direct2D render target. Used to create the bitmap.
// hnsPos:   The seek position.
// pSprite:  A Sprite object to hold the bitmap.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

HRESULT ThumbnailGenerator::CreateBitmap(
ID2D1RenderTarget *pRT, 
LONGLONG& hnsPos, 
Sprite *pSprite
)
{
HRESULT     hr = S_OK;
DWORD       dwFlags = 0;

BYTE        *pBitmapData = NULL;    // Bitmap data
DWORD       cbBitmapData = 0;       // Size of data, in bytes
LONGLONG    hnsTimeStamp = 0;
BOOL        bCanSeek = FALSE;       // Can the source seek?  
DWORD       cSkipped = 0;           // Number of skipped frames

IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = 0;
IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
ID2D1Bitmap *pBitmap = NULL;

hr = CanSeek(&bCanSeek);
if (FAILED(hr)) 
{ 
    return hr; 
}

if (bCanSeek && (hnsPos > 0))
{
    PROPVARIANT var;
    PropVariantInit(&var);

    var.vt = VT_I8;
    var.hVal.QuadPart = hnsPos;

    hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentPosition(GUID_NULL, var);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

}


// Pulls video frames from the source reader.

// NOTE: Seeking might be inaccurate, depending on the container
//       format and how the file was indexed. Therefore, the first
//       frame that we get might be earlier than the desired time.
//       If so, we skip up to MAX_FRAMES_TO_SKIP frames.

while (1)
{
    IMFSample *pSampleTmp = NULL;

    hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
        (DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        &dwFlags, 
        NULL, 
        &pSampleTmp
        );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

    if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (dwFlags & MF_SOURCE_READERF_CURRENTMEDIATYPECHANGED)
    {
        // Type change. Get the new format.
        hr = GetVideoFormat(&m_format);

        if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }
    }

    if (pSampleTmp == NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }

    // We got a sample. Hold onto it.

    SafeRelease(&pSample);

    pSample = pSampleTmp;
    pSample->AddRef();

    if (SUCCEEDED( pSample->GetSampleTime(&hnsTimeStamp) ))
    {
        // Keep going until we get a frame that is within tolerance of the
        // desired seek position, or until we skip MAX_FRAMES_TO_SKIP frames.

        // During this process, we might reach the end of the file, so we
        // always cache the last sample that we got (pSample).

        if ( (cSkipped < MAX_FRAMES_TO_SKIP) && 
             (hnsTimeStamp + SEEK_TOLERANCE < hnsPos) )  
        {
            SafeRelease(&pSampleTmp);

            ++cSkipped;
            continue;
        }
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSampleTmp);

    hnsPos = hnsTimeStamp;
    break;
 }

 if (pSample)
 {
    UINT32 pitch = 4 * m_format.imageWidthPels; 

    // Get the bitmap data from the sample, and use it to create a
    // Direct2D bitmap object. Then use the Direct2D bitmap to 
    // initialize the sprite.

    hr = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pBitmapData, NULL, &cbBitmapData);

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

    assert(cbBitmapData == (pitch * m_format.imageHeightPels));

    hr = pRT->CreateBitmap( 
        D2D1::SizeU(m_format.imageWidthPels, m_format.imageHeightPels),
        pBitmapData,
        pitch,
        D2D1::BitmapProperties( 
            // Format = RGB32
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE) 
            ),
        &pBitmap
        );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }

    pSprite->SetBitmap(pBitmap, m_format);
    }
    else
    {
    hr = MF_E_END_OF_STREAM;
    }

done:

if (pBitmapData)
{
    pBuffer->Unlock();
}
SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
SafeRelease(&pSample);
SafeRelease(&pBitmap);

return hr;
}
```

Instead of the bitmaps being placed inside the Sprite objects (passed in as an array), I want the method to return an array of Bitmaps. MSDN suggests Bitmap class does exist for C++ though I can't seem to include a reference to it for this class. What I want to do is compile this class as a DLL eventually and use it in my C# project where I can pass a uri to a movie and have it chopped up and returned as Bitmap frames from these methods. I can take care of the logic myself, I just need to know how I could make this code handle and return a `Bitmap[]` of the frames from the `CreateBitmaps()` method.

Comment: That paragraph was massive. I have to admit, I did not read it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Windows API, you can create a Bitmap. So, instead of doing:

```
pSprite->SetBitmap(pBitmap, m_format);
```

You should pass a pointer to a Bitmap object as a parameter to the CreateBitmap function and then use this in the function:

```
  *pBitmap =  new Bitmap(INT width, INT height, INT stride, PixelFormat format, BYTE *scan0);
```

In the above, replace *scan0 with the pointer to the bitmap data in bytes (which I believe in your code is pBitmap) and the rest of the information regarding the height, width, pixelFormat etc, from the m_Format variable.

This should work for you.

**Note:**  Please include all the GDI+ headers as Bitmap class is a part of it.

Hope this helps.

**P.S.** If you are averse to using the GDI+ classes, you can try the bitmap object which MSDN offers as part of Windows GDI. Though personally, I feel that it offers a lot less functionality and it takes longer to code.

Comment: Many thanks for your input, and sorry for not getting back here sooner... removing all the dependencies from the source code to the other parts I didn't need took a while! I have decided that the creation of Bitmaps is now probably an efficiency drain so am just going to read the data in the buffer from raw memory for speed. Thank you though for your suggestion, I have chosen it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Before O.P. Added more content:

The official C++ language specification does not support bitmaps.  It can support arrays though.

The common method is to find a framework, such as QT, wxWidgets, etc., and use their libraries for displaying bitmaps.

A more complex method is to use the Windows API directly.